# Тире при пропуске сказуемого

Tags: пунктуация

Есть правило:

> Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного
>   предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое)
>   восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска
>   делается пауза: Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно
>   плохо

Вопрос: ставится ли тире, если время глагола отличается? 

Например: Я был на работе, а сейчас [?] в автошколе.

Comment: а чего оно должно не ставиться? даже в этом правиле приведенном написано, что речь идет о "пропущенном члене предложения (обычно сказуемом)". Т.е. это может быть любое слово вообще, не только глагол, отличающееся по времени, падежу и т.п. Я всегда ставлю тире, если имеется в виду пропуск, и подразумевается пауза в речи. Т.е.  `сейчас — в автошколе` или `сейчас в автошколе`, если пропуск и пауза в виду не имелись. Я вообще с такими вещами не заморачивался никогда и если б мне кто-то сказал, что я "пишу неправильно, потому что вот где-то есть правило", то я б просто послал бы подальше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире может ставиться, а может не ставиться. Критерием является наличие или отсутствие паузы в речи.

1. Тире ставится при пропущенном члене предложения и наличии паузы (как уже замечено @user907860). Даже если пропущенный член отличается по времени, падежу и т.п. Главное, что пропущенный член **восстанавливается.**

> Идти дальше через трясину было опасно, оставаться — тоже.
>
> У него в глазах — как бы поскорее отделаться от меня.

2. Тире не ставится при отсутствии паузы.

> Алёша смотрел на них, а они на него. *(Достоевский)*
>
> Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку. *(Чехов)*

[Д.Э. Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93)

Comment: https://luchshe-molchi.livejournal.com/17685273.html?thread=154756633#t154756633
 / говорят, только после местоимения можно тире опускать

Comment: @Arioch Хорошо бы ссылку на источник правила.  На форуме по ссылке это выглядит как личное мнение участника и не более того.

Comment: @vitally Стоит ли в испорченный телефон играть? Просто спросите в блоге по ссылке. Тем более, там ещё одна ссылка, на этот форум, где тоже говорится, про местоимения